# Django DurationField and 00:00:00 versus NULL

Tags: django, null, timedelta

Using Django 3.2.7, python 3.9.x and Mysql 8.x.

With models like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
   period = models.DurationField('Period', null=False, blank=False, default=timedelta(days=1))

class Subobject(models.Model):
   object = models.ForeignKey(Object, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCASE)
   period = models.DurationField('Period', null=True, blank=True)
```

and the following query:

```
sub_objs = Subobject.objects.select_related(
    'object'
).annotate(
    actual_period=Case(
        When(
            period__isnull=False,
            then=F('period')
        ),
        default=F('object__period'),
        output_fields=models.DurationField()
    )
).filter(
    actual_period__gte=timedelta(seconds=3600)
)
```

Which could be humanly translated as: "for each subobject, assign a variable named `actual_period`, whose value is `period` when found 'locally' in each object, with a fallback to the parent `object.period` property when not; then filter, etc."

This works, but let us imagine a case where a subobject has to have a `period` property set to "no time at all", i.e., a timedelta == 0 seconds.

I tried setting a `subobject.period` field to `00:00:00` in the admin, or to `timedelta(seconds=0)` programmatically, and it seems django (Mysql?) *always* considers such a timedelta as being null. The consequence being that, in the above query, the parent object's `period` property is applied in the annotation.

Is this working as intended?
Is there a way to have django/mysql consider that a "zero-time timedelta" is not a `null` value?

Comment: What happens if you work with `actual_period=Coalesce('period', 'object_period')`? with `from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce`.

Comment: haaaa good idea for a fallback, will try and report back :-)

Comment: Can you look in the database what value is used for such timedelta? Is it really `NULL` in the database, or does the database considers this to be `0`?

Comment: column "period" is a bigint. When entering '00:00:00' in the django admin, value is set to 0

Comment: does it work with `Coalesce`?

Comment: `isnull=False` directly corresponds to `IS NOT NULL` in SQL, a bigint `0` does match that condition are you sure what you describe is happening or you might be mistaken?